# Custom Slick Codegen generate mapped case classes outside the `${container} trait`?

Tags: scala, slick, scala-2.11, slick-3.0, slick-codegen

Can Slick Codegen generate all the mapped case classes outside of the `${container} trait`
, so that they don't inherit its type? Maybe in another file altogether i.e. `Models.scala`?

```
// SuppliersRowsDAA.scala
import persistence.Tables

object SuppliersRowsDAA {
  case class Save(sup: Tables.SuppliersRow)
}
```

I get this compilation error:

```
[error] /app/src/main/scala/persistence/dal/SuppliersDAA.scala:5: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : persistence.Tables.SuppliersRow
[error]  required: SuppliersDAA.this.SuppliersRow
[error]     case Save(sup) ⇒ sender ! db.run(Suppliers += sup)
```

Using `Tables#SuppliersRow` import gives the same error.

If I manually cut & paste the `SuppliersRow` case class outside of the auto-generated `trait Tables` it works!

```
....

trait Tables {

....
}
case class SuppliersRow(id: Int, userId: Int, name: String)
//EOF
```

Comment: you should be able to do this immutably, but I don't have the time to look into it right now

Comment: `mkString()` is using `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder`, which has an __append__ complexity of  `aC` vs. `C` from `ListBuffer/MutableList ` http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: I don't see asymptotic complexity as an important subject when we are generating a few strings at compile time

Comment: correctness and clarity are much more important concerns. immutability helps here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending the original `docWithCode` of `EntityType` to `super.packageCode()`:

```
import slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator
import slick.model.Model
import scala.collection.mutable

class CustomizedCodeGenerator(model: Model) extends SourceCodeGenerator(model) {
  val models = new mutable.MutableList[String]

  override def packageCode(profile: String, pkg: String, container: String, parentType: Option[String]): String = {
    super.packageCode(profile, pkg, container, parentType) + "\n" + outsideCode
  }

  def outsideCode = s"${indent(models.mkString("\n"))}"

  override def Table = new Table(_) {
    override def EntityType = new EntityTypeDef {
      override def docWithCode: String = {
        models += super.docWithCode.toString + "\n"
        ""
      }
    }
  }

}
```