# Why does Play project fail with "implicit value ... is not applicable here" after upgrading to Slick 3.0?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0

After upgrading to Slick 3.0 and Play! 2.4, I got this pretty dependency injection feature, but I faced with serialization problems.
My Application is simple rest server.

This is the exception which I get

```
type mismatch; 
found : play.api.libs.json.OWrites[ReportsDatabase.this.PostEntity] 
required: play.api.libs.json.Writes[ApiRoot.this.noiseModel.PostEntity] 
Note: implicit value PostWrites is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
```

This is my entity

```
val posts = TableQuery[Posts]

case class PostEntity(id: Long, user: Long, text: String, date: LocalDate, lat: Double, lon: Double, pictureID: Long, soundId: Long)

class Posts(tag: Tag) extends Table[PostEntity](tag, "post") {
    implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, String](dateFormatter.print(_), dateFormatter.parseLocalDate)

    def id = column[Long]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    def userId = column[Long]("userId")
    def text = column[String]("text")
    def date = column[LocalDate]("date_post")
    def lat = column[Double]("lat")
    def lon = column[Double]("lon")
    def pictureId = column[Long]("pictureID")
    def soundId = column[Long]("soundId")
    def * = (id, userId, text, date, lat, lon, pictureId, soundId) <>(PostEntity.tupled, PostEntity.unapply)

    def user = foreignKey("post_user_FK", userId, users)(_.id)
```

}

Here is method to get a list of posts

```
def getPostList: Future[Seq[PostEntity]] = db.run(posts.result)
```

My controller starts like this

```
class ApiRoot @Inject() (noiseDao: NoiseModel, noiseModel: ReportsDatabase) extends Controller {
  import noiseModel._

  implicit val PostWrites = Json.writes[noiseModel.PostEntity]

  def getPostStream = Action.async { implicit request =>
     noiseDao.getPostList.map{posts =>
       Ok(toJson(posts))
    }
  }

  def getPost(id: Long) = Action.async { implicit request =>
     noiseDao.getPost(id).map{ post =>
       Ok(toJson(post))
  }

}
```

I haven't found any information in the Internet regarding this problem. Found questions, but any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is to move `implicit val PostWrites` to companion object `Posts` or closer to the DI library (don't know Play that much to offer more help).

It happens because of the way DI works in general - first an instance, and then all the goodies are available that are inside the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem upgrading my application to Play! 2.4. If you use the slick code generator for your entities you need to create a custom generator like the one in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32070115